# Rails scope to order by counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to show the "Top 10" for users with the most comments.

Comment has `belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :comments_count`.

User has:

```
def self.top_by_comment_count
  order('comments_count desc').limit(10).to_a
end
```

This works fine on my local machine, but on a Heroku deploy I get all the users with *no* comments at the top.

I thought this would be a relatively straightforward task, but I'm beating my head against it.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have NULLs in the `comments_count` column.

The best thing would be to not have NULLs there at all, a little migration with this would fix that:

```
change_column_default :users, :comments_count, 0
change_column_null :users, :comments_count, false
```

Alternatively, you could tell PostgreSQL where you want the NULLs:

```
order('comments_count desc nulls last')
```

But really, just change the column's nullity and default to avoid the SQL NULLs altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Probably problem is that PostgreSQL orders `NULL` as not you expected

Users who have `comments_count` as `nil` are on the top of this list

How to fix it. You can run in rails console on Heroku

```
User.where(comments_count: nil).find_each { |user| User.reset_counters(user.id, :comments) }
```

This command will reset `NULL` to `0`

Also I recommend to add new migration with default `0` of `comments_count`

Something like this

```
change_column :users, :comments_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false
```

Comment: `reset_counters` is just as this method illustration. Of course you can use `User.where(comments_count: nil).update_all(comments_count: 0)`